# Qt Creator and Qt Desktop Application's Menus go invisible or missing

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator

This is an issue I've been experience in Qt Creator itself, as well as any application created using Qt Creator. The MainWindow menubar's popup menus go invisible after the application has been open for a long period of time. You can click on the File menu and nothing will appear, however you can use the arrow keys or even your cursor and hover over 'where the menu item would be' and click to execute. However the menu is not visible. Here is a screenshot after I've clicked on the file menu in Qt Creator.

You can see the File menu does not display. Even right-click menus in the Projects panel do not show. However I can still right-click in the Code editor and those menus work as expected.

Like i mentioned this issue has been around for several years, on multiple machines with different versions of Qt Creator. Does anyone else have exp or information about this?

I'm currently experiencing this issue on Windows 7 and Windows 10 using Qt Creator 4.4.0 and in Applications built using 5.11.1 MinGW 32Bit

[image]

**Update**: I discovered that the menus to actually appear, but they are showing behind the parent application which is QtCreator itself.

[image]

Comment: Please mention the recent Qt and Qt creator version you faced the problem with along with OS

Comment: updated to show that information.

Comment: Do you still have that issue? Sounds to me to a graphics card related issue. Can't say for sure though. Did you try QtCreator 4.6 or later?

Comment: Yes, this exists in Qt Creator itself, as well as any application built using Qt Creator. The issue is reproducible on multiple computers. As of right now it's happened on over 8 computers. All using windows 10.